# head function for empty list issue

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I want to use 'head' function inside map.
The problem is the 'head' function only accepts non-empty list.
I have list of list:

```
let ll =[["dog", "cat"], ["pig", "cow"], []]
```

I need to iterate the list of list twice

```
let listOne = filter(\x -> if length x > 0) ll
map(\x -> head x) listOne
```

I'm wondering whether I can iterate the list of list once or put a "if condition" inside the map without the 'filter'

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to have happen for an empty list?  Just filter/ignore it?  Why does filter not do what you want?

Comment: filter only removes the empty list, but I want to use 'head' and do something on the head element.

Comment: But an empty list has no head.  What did you need that map + filter doesn't do?  If you only concern was iterating the list twice, it doesn't.  Those operations are evaluated lazily.

Comment: Never use `head, tail, !!`. Just pretend they don't exist. `length` is another function which is often abused, hence best avoided when possible. The code above also suffers from "boolean blindness" (you can google that): instead of checking if a list is nonempty and taking its first element in the same step, it checks for non-emptiness only to build a boolean (`length x > 0`), effectively discarding the first element. Later on, we need that, but it's too late. Pattern matching helps us avoid booleans, and retaining the crucial information at hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in fact you can write it as a *list comprehension* statement, and use *pattern matching instead*:

```
result = [ h | (h:_) <- ll ]
```

or as a function:

```
heads :: [[a]] -> [a]
heads ll = [ h | (h:_) <- ll ]
```

So here we use the pattern `(h:_)` which matches all non-empty lists, and we directly obtain the head `h` of such list and add it to the list. If you use a pattern in list comprehension (on the left side of the left arrow `<-`, it will skip the elements that do not match the pattern).

This is also *more* safe than using `length`, since `length` will get stuck into an infinite loop if you are working with *infinite* lists. Furthermore by using patterns over the non-total `head` function, we have more *syntactical* guarantees that this function will work (yes, once the non-empty elements are filtered, we are of course certain that `head` will not result in errors, but we only know this because we have information about the `head` function).

Note that your attempt will result in a syntax error, since you use an `if`, without a `then` and `else` part.

Alternatively, we can, like [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870762/head-function-for-empty-list-issue/47870817?noredirect=1#comment82714614_47870817) says, write the `heads` function differently, for instance using:

```
heads :: [[a]] -> [a]
heads ll = concatMap (take 1) ll
```

or by using the *bind* of the list monad:

```
heads :: [[a]] -> [a]
heads = (take 1 =<<)
```

or we can transpose the 2d list. In that case the first row contains all the heads of the lists. Since it is however not guaranteed that there is such a row, we can append an empty list at the end, like:

```
heads :: [[a]] -> [a]
heads = head . (++ [[]]) . transpose
```

Comment: Another fun spelling of the same idea: `heads = concatMap (take 1)`. A completely different idea: `heads = head . (++[[]]) . transpose`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I really like these :) , especially the first one.